# Partition keeps switching to read only

Tags: 14.04, read-only, boot-partition

For the past week my server has been having issues where the boot partition is switching to read only mode.

I managed to boot into rescue mode and to check the partitions

```
fsck.ext4 -n /dev/sda1
```

But it looks like everything is fine

```
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Warning!  /dev/sda1 is in use.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sda1: clean, 49455/3203072 files, 633065/12799728 blocks
```

Any idea what's happening or which tests I should do to understand what's going on?

Usually rebooting will work properly for a few days/hours, but that's just a workaround for now...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I remember all partitions mounts as RO in rescue mode, so you need to remount it by hand:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /mountpoint
```

Also I would suggest you to check your drive's S.M.A.R.T. status.